Rellenar columnas con valores por defecto en caso de que no exista en el rango de fechas definido
Tengo que generar una consulta en la cual se obtienen registros en un rango de fecha, para cada fecha siempre deben existir en la columna de archivos 2 registros.
Hay fechas en donde solo aparece 1 solo archivo por ende se debe autocompletar el nombre del segundo archivo con un nombre por defecto, ex: ARCHIVO_X_YYYYMMDD.txt.
Esta es la estructura de la tabla Archivos:



FILEID
ARCHIVO
FECHA
REGISTROS




1312312
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240515.txt
2024-05-15 14:59:00.0
300


2312333
ARCHIVO_XYZ_20240515.txt
2024-05-15 14:59:00.0
200


4343434
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240516.txt
2024-05-16 14:29:00.0
100


4314144
ARCHIVO_XYZ_20240516.txt
2024-05-16 14:29:00.0
500


543545
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240517.txt
2024-05-17 14:19:39.0
240


654545
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240518.txt
2024-05-18 14:59:39.0
450


45454
ARCHIVO_XYZ_20240518.txt
2024-05-18 14:59:39.0
510


85454
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240519.txt
2024-05-19 14:59:39.0
510


9545454
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240520.txt
2024-05-20 14:59:39.0
510



Como se observa en la tabla mencionada, por cada fecha el patron a seguir deberia ser:

ARCHIVO_ABC_FECHA.txt (ARCHIVO_ABC_20240515.txt)
ARCHIVO_XYZ_FECHA.txt (ARCHIVO_XYZ_20240515.txt)

Los registros de la fecha 17, 19 y 20 solo poseen uno de los archivos asi que el otro archivo se debe autocompletar, la fecha que debe poseer es la del archivo presente y el valor de registros en 0, para verse de la siguiente manera:



ID
ARCHIVO
FECHA
REGISTROS




543545
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240517.txt
2024-05-17 14:19:39.0
240


0
ARCHIVO_XYZ_20240517.txt
2024-05-17 14:19:39.0
0


85454
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240519.txt
2024-05-19 14:59:39.0
510


0
ARCHIVO_XYZ_20240519.txt
2024-05-19 14:59:39.0
0


9545454
ARCHIVO_ABC_20240520.txt
2024-05-20 14:59:39.0
510



ARCHIVO_XYZ_20240520.txt
2024-05-20 14:59:39.0
0



Por el momento solo obtengo los registros en el rango de fechas pero no logro dar con la forma de rellenas las filas  con los datos que no existen.
SELECT
    ID AS IDARCHIVO
    , ARCHIVO
    , FECHA
    , REGISTROS
FROM ARCHIVOS
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -7 AND CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY FECHA DESC


Puedes construir la solución valiéndote primero de un CTE para determinar las fechas que están en el rango de la búsqueda, es decir:
select distinct fecha from Archivos where fecha between...

Ya con esta información, encontrar los registros que faltan de uno o de otro, se convertiría en algo como:
select *
  from Fechas --el nombre del CTE
 where not exists (select 1 from Archivos where fecha = Fechas.fecha and Archivo like 'ARCHIVO_ABC_%')

El conjunto de datos final sería la unión de los registros que existen, más los registros generados para los que no existen, por ejemplo:
with
Fechas as (
select distinct fecha
  from Archivos
 where fecha between current_date - 7 and current_date
)
  select *
    from Archivos
   where fecha between current_date - 7 and current_date
union all
  select   0 fileid
         ,   'ARCHIVO_ABC_' 
           +  cast(cast(cast(fecha as timestamp) as format 'YYYYMMDD') as varchar(8))
           + '.txt' Archivo
         , fecha
         , 0 registros
    from fechas
   where not exists (select 1 from Archivos where Archivos.fecha = Fechas.fecha and archivo like 'ARCHIVO_ABC_%')
union all
  select   0 fileid
         ,   'ARCHIVO_XYZ_' 
           +  cast(cast(cast(fecha as timestamp) as format 'YYYYMMDD') as varchar(8))
           + '.txt' Archivo
         , fecha
         , 0 registros
    from fechas
   where not exists (select 1 from Archivos where Archivos.fecha = Fechas.fecha and archivo like 'ARCHIVO_XYZ_%')
order by fecha, Archivo;

